# Append value to result of FILTER function in order to call XIRR function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to call the `XIRR` function using a filtered array of data, but I need to append one additional value to each array

The baseline idea is the following formula that gathers the cashflow/date arrays from the K/A columns using the `FILTER` function:

```
=XIRR(FILTER(K2:K1000,C2:C1000=M2),FILTER(A2:A1000,C2:C1000=M2))
```

However, the arrays returned by `FILTER` are missing data for the current day that exists elsewhere in the sheet.  So I want something similar to:

```
=XIRR(FILTER(K2:K1000,C2:C1000=M2) + {Q2},FILTER(A2:A1000,C2:C1000=M2) + {TODAY()})
```

Where `Q2` and `TODAY()` are the additional pieces of data.  Obviously the above formula doesn't actually work, but is there any way to append data to an existing array like that directly inside a formula(without using a scratch area)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new array with appended values using curly bracket and semicolon:

```
=XIRR({FILTER(K2:K1000,C2:C1000=M2);Q2},{FILTER(A2:A1000,C2:C1000=M2);TODAY()})
```

Sample Usage:

[image]

Reference:

[Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)